# Leading wildcard character throws error in Lucene.NET

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, wildcard

If the search query contains a leading wildcard character (`*` or `?`), the `QueryParser`'s `Parse` function throws an error.

```
Dim q As String = "*abc"
Dim qp As New QueryParser("text", New StandardAnalyzer())
Dim query As Query = qp.Parse(q)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem in Lucene.NET v2.0.0.4?

Comment: There are several different ways of handling these kinds of queries. I'd suggest that wildcard queries are generally a "bad thing". If you could give a little more context? Num of docs; num of fields per doc; approx size of text fields; are you trying to find the ending of words; is it a common suffix; are the terms "codes" or words from regular text...  any other info would help

Answer (score 5):

Set [QueryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard Method](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard.html) to true. The API page states that "this can produce very slow queries on big indexes" though.

Comment: A *bad* idea. Although this may "work" it will be _very_ slow, especially as the index gets bigger. Use something like the NGramAnalyzer from Contrib (mentioned in another answer)

Comment: @AndyPook My answer is valid correctness-wise, and I did mention the potential performance issue in my answer. **Will** it be "_very_ slow" to the point of being a deal-breaker for OP? Neither of us would know, since the question does not include enough details (e.g. index size, whether it is a one-off or recurring query). Also, the NGram approach has its own limitations (e.g. OP needs to be able to change the index to use NGram) and drawbacks (e.g. the index might get bigger because there are more terms).

Comment: Yup you are correct it will "work". But perf will degrade pretty quickly as it must examine *every* term in that field. Sure, with ngram, the index size may increase (a little) such is the way of data stores. Adding an index to a sql db adds size but avoids table scans. You are also right that we don't know much about the OPs specific scenario, Lets ask...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to use a [WildcardQuery](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardQuery.html), but

> ...In order to prevent extremely slow
>   WildcardQueries, a Wildcard term
>   should not start with one of the
>   wildcards...

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid wildcard queries by utilizing `NGramFilter` for your index analyzer. Than you have to use `search_analyzer` without `NGramFilter`. This way you can search similar to `like "%text%"` without even needing wildcards. You just enter 'abc' and your index would be searched for all entries containing 'abc' very quickly.

Comment: The NGram bits are found in the Contrib project