# Lucene character sequence search in a term

Tags: lucene

I want to find a character sequence (more than three characters) within a Term. I have tried *character_sequence*(I know this is not recommended), but it does not return result if the character sequence itself is equivalent to the Term.

For example, if the terms are "testsomething", "somethingtest" and "sometestthing", I want all these Terms in my search result if the text "test" is searched.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prefix queries are by default supported in lucene and to support suffix queries you might have to do a little work. You can check [How to query lucene with "like" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307890/how-to-query-lucene-with-like-operator)