# Lucene Search with Like Clause

Tags: asp.net, lucene.net, lucene

I have title search with Lucene .net and facing problem with LIKE clause search.

I have tried below terms but it is matching whole word.

```
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("title", word.ToLower())), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Also tried

```
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("title", word.ToLower())), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Any idea how to apply LIKE clause?

Comment: If you were looking for SQL-type LIKE syntax, there are questions for that already in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307890/how-to-query-lucene-with-like-operator

Comment: Need more clarification. What do you mean with "LIKE clause" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you are probably looking for either [Prefix](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d4/d9c/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_prefix_query.html) or [Wildcard](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/d1b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_wildcard_query.html) queries.

In general, I'd recommend getting some level of understanding of the instantiable subclasses of Query, [listed here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html).