# how to get search hits when at least one character present in field value using lucene search

Tags: lucene

How do I get search hits when at least one character searched is present in a  field's value, using lucene search?

I got search hits only when I search with a complete word.

Example:
**Hello world**

In above example, if I enter "Hello", then I will get a hit, but not if I enter "Hel"

Here is my code to get hits:

```
QueryParser parser = null;
Query query = null;
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, new HashSet());
BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(32767);
parser = new QueryParser("fieldname", analyzer);
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
query = parser.parse("searchString");
TopDocs topResultDocs = searcher.search(query, null, 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Always append `*` to the query to get all suffix matches: `Hel*` will match `Hello`.

Comment: if Hel present in some string like "abcHelbbc  abcdef" also i need to get hit

Comment: If you are trying to replicate SQL `LIKE '%foo%'` behaviour, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307890/how-to-query-lucene-with-like-operator

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, you might want to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is how this site works. Thank you!

Comment: for example: In 'Hi Hello world'  sentence I need to get hit if i enter  'Hello wo' .what i need to do

Comment: I got solution:TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(field, new StringReader(searchString)); List tokens = new ArrayList(); TermAttribute termAttribute = (TermAttribute) tokenStream.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class); while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) { String term = termAttribute.term(); tokens.add(term); } BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery(); for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) { booleanQuery.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term(field, tokens.get(i).toString())), Occur.MUST); } TopDocs topResultDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, null, 20);