# how to perform a contains search rather than starts with using lucene java

Tags: java, lucene

I have  the following code but this returns exact wort matches. I know Lucene generates words as tokens. Is there a way to search in which we use contains rather than exact matches

```
      analyzer   = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
      index = new RAMDirectory();
       Query q = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, stockArr, analyzer).parse(querystr);
```

Comment: And what is your `querystr`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Leading wildcard character throws error in Lucene.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468279/leading-wildcard-character-throws-error-in-lucene-net)